# Not able to include plugin stylsheet in front end (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to include my plugin stylesheet on my WP website (frontend), but for some reason it's not working.

```
function init_gallery_scripts() {
  if (is_admin() ) {
    // This works!
    wp_enqueue_script('gallery',  plugins_url('js/gallery.js',__FILE__),array('wp-filebrowser'));        
    wp_enqueue_style('gallery-css', plugins_url('style/gallery.css',__FILE__));
  } 
  else {
    // This is not woking. Why?
    wp_enqueue_style('gallery-front-css', plugins_url('style/gallery_front.css',__FILE__));
  }
}
```

I've also tried this with no success:

```
wp_register_style('gallery-front-css', plugins_url('style/gallery_front.css',__FILE__));
wp_enqueue_style('gallery-front-css');
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What action are you using to call init_gallery_scripts()?

Comment: Ah! I was using `admin_init`. When I changed this to `init` it loads front end as well. Should I have two different calls? One for admin and one for init? Post your comment as answer so I can accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to awats, I found my "stupid" error.

The `add_action()` command was set to initiate on `admin_init`, thus never getting triggered in frontend (because you are not backend in admin section).

Changing this to trigger on `init` solved the issue.

Comment: Can you please write the function in detail? I am also facing same issue ?